# How to evaluate the following integral along the principal branch of Logz

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

$\int_{-1}^1 \log{z} dz$, where the principal branch of $\log z$ is the negative real axis, and hence $Arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi]$. \

This is what I did.

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1 \log{z} dz &= z\log z - z|_{-1}^1 \\
&= \log(1) - 1 - (-\log(-1) + 1) \\
&= \log(1) + \log(-1) - 2 \\
&= ln|1| + iArg(1) + \ln|-1| + iArg(-1) - 2 \\
&= i\pi - 2
\end{align*}

I used FTC, but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to since the line segment from $-1$ to $1$ goes through the branch cut. So I'm pretty sure my computation does not make theoretical sense. So where have I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamental Theorem of Calculus works for a complex function $f$, when there is a function $F$ such that its complex derivative exists and equal to $f$ along the integration path. For the complex derivative to exist, $F$ should be holomorphic in some *open set*, that includes the path of integration.

You can change the definition of  $\log$ by taking $\operatorname{Arg}(z)\in(-\pi+\varepsilon, \pi+\varepsilon]$ for some small $\varepsilon>0$. Then $F(z) = z\log z - z$ will be holomorphic in open sets

$$
\begin{align}
&U_1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \;| \; \operatorname{Arg}(z) \in (\pi-\varepsilon, \pi+\varepsilon) \text{ and } z\ne 0\}, \\
&U_2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \;| \; \operatorname{Arg}(z) \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \text{ and } z\ne 0\},
\end{align}
$$
and its complex derivative will equal to $f(z) = \log z$ within this sets.

You can then calculate
$$
\int_{-1}^{0} f(z)dz = -1+i\pi \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{0}^{1} f(z)dz = -1
$$
without any worries.

Comment: @MattAdamBarnes In your case all incorrectness is "removable". The brach cut can be moved a little bit without changing the formula for $f$ and $F$, and the singularity at $z=0$ is removable for $F(z)$. Your computation would fail for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$, since the singularity at $z=0$ is essential for $F(z)=\log z$.